# How to find in which Solaris OS version the binary was built

Tags: solaris

We have an old OLD binary which was built on OLD Solaris OS (pre Solaris 10 version).
I need to rebuild some of its code in same Old Solaris OS.. No one know in which version it was built and no machine details available..

The binary is running on Solaris 10. But for some backward compatibility purpose (believe me.. ) they still wanted it to built on Old Solaris.

is there a way to find in which OS version that binary was build..? (last stupid belief).

Comment: Try `strings -a` on the binary and hope there's something useful in the output.  But assuming this is for SPARC hardware, what happens if your software was built 25 years ago on Solaris 2.5.1 and the oldest version of Solaris you have running is Solaris 7?  Where are "they" going to get a copy of Solaris 2.5.1?  Where are "they" going to get hardware that can run Solaris 2.5.1?  Just build the software on the oldest version of Solaris and the oldest hardware you have.  If "they" come up with older OS versions and/or older hardware, **THEN** you can build the software on that OS and hardware.

Comment: (cont) "But is **HAS** to be backwards compatible!"  Umm, no it doesn't if you don't have that OS version and/or hardware to run it on.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the binary was built, the command:

```
mcs -p binary
```

might give you a good hint.

Otherwise, as Andrew suggested (with optional filtering added):

```
strings -a binary | egrep -i "solaris|sunos|version|5\."
```